# Убрать класс (скрыть div) при повторном клике на определённую ссылку

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, menu

Всё работает нормально однако не получается сделать так, чтобы при втором клике на ссылку div по этому адресу скрывался. Т.е. кликаем на `link1` открывается `div` с `content1`, при втором клике на эту ссылку, `div` скрывается. Важно сохранить всю остальную функциональность.

```js
// Dropdown menu functionality

var anchor = $('.main_nav li a');
var menu = $('.menu');

anchor.click(function () {
  if ($(this.getAttribute('href')).hasClass('is-visible')) {
    this.parent.siblings().removeClass('is-visible');
    menu.not(this).removeClass('is-visible').addClass('is-hidden');
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    anchor.not(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this.getAttribute('href')).removeClass('is-hidden').addClass('is-visible');
  }
  return false;
});


$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
  // if the target of the click isn't the menu nor a decendant of the menu
  if (!menu.is(e.target) && menu.has(e.target).length === 0) {
    anchor.removeClass('active');
    menu.removeClass('is-visible').addClass('is-hidden');
  }
});

// hide menu when clicking on links
$('.menu a').click(function () {
    anchor.removeClass('active');
    menu.removeClass('is-visible').addClass('is-hidden');
});
```

```css
.is-hidden {
  display: none;
}

.is-visible {
  display: block;
}

.active {
  background: green;
}

.main_nav {
  padding: 0;
}
.main_nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 180px;
  background: grey;
  text-align: center;
}
.main_nav li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 30px 0 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu {
  background: grey;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Main navigation -->
<ul class="main_nav">
  <li><a href="#link_1">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#link_2">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#link_3">Link 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#link_4">Link 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#link_5">Link 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#link_6">Link 6</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Div's -->
<div class="menu is-hidden" id="link_1">
  <a href="#">Content 1</a>
</div>
<div class="menu is-hidden" id="link_2">
  <a href="#">Content 2</a>
</div>
<div class="menu is-hidden" id="link_3">
  <a href="#">Content 3</a>
</div>
<div class="menu is-hidden" id="link_4">
  <a href="#">Content 4</a>
</div>
<div class="menu is-hidden" id="link_5">
  <a href="#">Content 5</a>
</div>
<div class="menu is-hidden" id="link_6">
  <a href="#">Content 6</a>
</div>
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KdvbVX) содержащий тоже самое.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам сильно мешало событие `$(document).mouseup()`.
Его убрать и добавить еще один раз `menu.removeClass('is-visible').addClass('is-hidden');`.
Вот, посмотрите:

```js
// Dropdown menu functionality

var anchor = $('.main_nav li a');
var menu = $('.menu');

anchor.click(function () {
  if ($(this.getAttribute('href')).hasClass('is-visible')) {
    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('is-visible');
    menu.not(this).removeClass('is-visible').addClass('is-hidden');
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    menu.removeClass('is-visible').addClass('is-hidden');
    anchor.not(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this.getAttribute('href')).removeClass('is-hidden').addClass('is-visible');
  }
  return false;
});

$('body').click(function(e) { 
    var el = e.target || e.srcElement; 
    if (!$(el).closest('.menu').length && !$(el).closest('.main_nav li a').length) { 
        anchor.removeClass('active'); 
        menu.removeClass('is-visible').addClass('is-hidden'); 
    } 
}); 

// hide menu when clicking on links
$('.menu a').click(function () {
    anchor.removeClass('active');
    menu.removeClass('is-visible').addClass('is-hidden');
});
```

```css
.is-hidden {
  display: none;
}

.is-visible {
  display: block;
}

.active {
  background: green;
}

.main_nav {
  padding: 0;
}
.main_nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 180px;
  background: grey;
  text-align: center;
}
.main_nav li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 30px 0 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu {
  background: grey;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Main navigation -->
<ul class="main_nav">
  <li><a href="#link_1">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#link_2">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#link_3">Link 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#link_4">Link 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#link_5">Link 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#link_6">Link 6</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Div's -->
<div class="menu is-hidden" id="link_1">
  <a href="#">Content 1</a>
</div>
<div class="menu is-hidden" id="link_2">
  <a href="#">Content 2</a>
</div>
<div class="menu is-hidden" id="link_3">
  <a href="#">Content 3</a>
</div>
<div class="menu is-hidden" id="link_4">
  <a href="#">Content 4</a>
</div>
<div class="menu is-hidden" id="link_5">
  <a href="#">Content 5</a>
</div>
<div class="menu is-hidden" id="link_6">
  <a href="#">Content 6</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Да, всё отлично, однако как сохранить функционал того, чтобы по клику вне открытой зоны меню открытый `div` скрывался?

Comment: ааааааааа, вот этот функционал я пропустил.... ща подумаем...

Comment: Добавьте
$('body').click(function(e) {
 var el = e.target || e.srcElement;
    
    if (!$(el).closest('.menu').length && !$(el).closest('.main_nav li a').length) {
     anchor.removeClass('active');
     menu.removeClass('is-visible').addClass('is-hidden');
    }
});
И будет закрываться при клике на свободную область

Comment: Благодарю вас! Отличное дополнение